# Low-rank approximation over finite fields

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields, additive-combinatorics

Consider the finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$ with prime $p$. Let $I=\{ 0,1,2,...,|I|-1 \}\subset \mathbb{F}_p$ be an "interval".

What can be the largest size $|I|$, such that there exists a $2\times 2$ matrix $M$ such that for any $a,b,c,d \in I$, the matrix

$ M +\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}  
$

has full rank? Using various methods (combinatorial Nullstellensatz http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~nogaa/PDFS/null2.pdf, Schwarz-Zippel lemma https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz%E2%80%93Zippel_lemma) one can show that this holds as long as $|I|\ll p^{1/4}$ (this does not really use the fact that $I$ is the "interval"). One can directly show (using that $I$ is the "interval") that whenever $|I|\ll p^{1/2}$, we can choose $M$ to be a scalar matrix  with $(p-1)/2$ in the diagonal.

The question is whether there is an upper bound for $|I|$. Ideally, I hope that the statement holds for any $|I| \gg p^{1-\varepsilon}$. Is it plausible that the bound will improve if we consider larger matrices?

Comment: Doesn't your first paragraph imply $|I|=|I|+1$?

Comment: You are right, fixed that.

Comment: I am wondering what character sums and Polya-Vingoradov will say about this? I hope to find a bit of time to think about it later.